# How to customize Application class conditionally?

Tags: java, android

I have customized `Application` class in my app to initialize some global objects.

But I noticed that this `Application` class runs not only in normal app start, but in **other occasions like unit testing**. This is not desirable, because those initializations in `Application` class may have side effects on the test results.

So is there any way in `Application` class to find out if the application is running for a normal usage by user, or for other purposes?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        if (isNormalRun())    //<-- How to implement this?
            initGlobalObjects();
    }

    private void initGlobalObjects()
    {
        SomeClass.initializeInstance(this);
        OtherClass.initializeInstance(this);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is is possible to find out if an Android application runs as part of an instrumentation test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776689/is-is-possible-to-find-out-if-an-android-application-runs-as-part-of-an-instrume)

Comment: *This is not desirable, because those initializations in Application class may have side effects on the test results.* that can be an indication of bad design. How do they affect it exactly?

Comment: @Tim The `SomeClass` and `OtherClass` in the sample code are singletons and their instances are being created here and being used in many places, possibly including the unit under test.

Comment: This is exactly why you should not customize `Application` or use global state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try "Build Variants" which have been released by Google recently.
You could define a new product flavour like this (example by Google):

```
    ...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs { ... }
    buildTypes { ... }
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.demo"
            versionName "1.0-demo"
        }
        full {
            applicationId "com.buildsystemexample.app.full"
            versionName "1.0-full"
        }
    }
}
...
```

Then add a source directory to your project. Each product flavour corresponds to a source directory below `/src/`. You may add resources, classes, values etc. to each flavour. To solve your specific problem you should place a `Application` class in every flavours source directory and develop them separate from each other.

[Documentation on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants)

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately I'm working on a legacy project in Eclipse.

Comment: It's never too late to switch, but i know how bad this works. You should try the Eclipse import assistant in Android Studio and see if it fails badly ;)

Comment: @perror I added some more content and referenced the OPs problem.

Answer (score 1):

What do you regard as 'normal run' ?

You can define a method in your Application class which you will invoke from `onCreate()` of your `MainActivity`. For example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ...
    public void deferredInit() {
        // Init some variables here
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).deferredInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: By "normal" I mean if it is launched by user; not for example by test runners. This approach is interesting. If I fail to find a direct solution, I'll use this design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file of properties, for example in the test environment parameterize the file for test, in the production environment parameterize the file with parameter for this situation.

Comment: Care to explain more or provide a link?

Comment: it's seems that this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files